# How to generate an auto-incremented id after calculating the array length in Kendo Ui?

Tags: kendo-ui

I have an array of 3 data, where the value field is the id. I want to generate auto incremented id after calculating the length of the array. I tried the total() method but , it is not working...

The code snippet,

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var GSList = new Array (
    {"value":"1","text":"System1","GSID":"A1000"},
    {"value":"2","text":"System2","GSID":"A1001"},
    {"value":"3","text":"System3","GSID":"A1002"} );

// *************Build the data source for the items*********************
var GSDS = new kendo.data.DataSource({ data: GSList });

$("#listViewSystem").kendoListView({
 dataSource: GSDS,
 template: "<div>#:value# #:text#</div>",
 selectable: true

});
GSDS.read();

var currentID = $("#listViewSystem").dataSource.total();


// Handle adding a new system


$('#addGS').click(function(e){
var listViewGS = $("#listViewSystem").data('kendoListView');   

currentID+= 1;

listViewGS.dataSource.insert({
    value: currentID,
    text: $('#AddGathrSysName').val()



});

e.preventDefault();
```

});
})

Comment: here is a dojo with your code working. http://dojo.telerik.com/aQefe The only thing I have fixed is the currentID assignment as you are missing the **data('kendoListView')** reference to get the total.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. It is working properly now !!!!

Comment: not a problem. If you want I can provide the response as an answer if you want to accept it.

Comment: Sure... Definitely !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

copied from my original comment on fixing this issue:

here is a dojo with your code working. [auto increment id](http://dojo.telerik.com/aQefe) The only thing I have fixed is the currentID assignment as you are missing the data('kendoListView') reference to get the total.